# Read a String column as Map with HIbernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i have a column in Database with a String, i.e. '{es:title_es,en:title_en}'
So, I need read it as a Map<String,String>, it will be for I18N.
I need the map with the language as key and label as value.
I use Hiberante 3.3.2 and Java 8 and SQL Server.

Is any chance to obtain this map in the EntityClass? This will be usefull because any relationship with this entity will have the correct representation and not a simple string.
And the behavior keep encapsulated.

Table :
OID CODE TITLES
1   XXX  **'{es:title_es,en:title_en}'**

Entity :

````
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class EntityClass {
    private Long oid;
    private String code;
    private String titles;  ---> i have this but i want private Map<String, String>

    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Column(name = "TITLES", nullable = false)
    public String getTitles() {
        return descriptions;
    }  ----> this work fine, but here i want to get directly the Map, 
}```
````

Comment: What database type do you use for the `TITLES` column? What database do you use?

Comment: yes, I already wrote it down in the description

Comment: You can do this with an `AttributeConverter<..>`, but this is a really bad idea IMHO; a Map will slow down your application and increase your queries overhead big time. You should probably consider better technical alternatives.